# problem with SQL CE and orderby linq clause

Tags: linq, sql-server-ce, sql-order-by

I am using linq with SQL CE, but for a simple query like this:

```
var points=from i in this.DomainBoundaryPoints orderby i.Index select i;
```

I get this error:

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<DAL.DomainBoundaryPoint>'.  'OrderBy' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?
```

Does SQL CE support 'order by' TSQL clause? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course SQL CE supports `orderby`...

Try to do what the error message tells you...

- add a reference to `System.Core` if it's not there
- add a using directive for `System.Linq`

Comment: it was my fault. I just forgot System.Linq. ;)